# The viewport should be 360x640, not 360x568. Why?

Tags: css, mobile, height, viewport, screen-resolution

My phones resolution is 720x1280
but when viewed by [viewportsizes.com/mine/](http://viewportsizes.com/mine/) , it says the viewport 320x568.
If the viewport shrunk, then that means 720 divided by 2 is 360 and 1280 divided by 2 is 640. So the viewport should be 360x640. The height should be 640 instead of 568. So why does the height appear to be 568 instead of 640?

Comment: The viewport is divided by the pixel density, it's 3 on my phone, so the resolution shows 1080/3=360 width; and 1920/3=640, but because some space is taken from the notifications bar, controls on the bottom, and the browser toolbar, it ends up with 511 height. But if you go to settings on the browser, and "request desktop website", it should show you the full viewport as will be calculated with pixel density of 1.

Comment: How do you get the pixel density of a phone?

Comment: I'm not sure how it is calculated, but [this website](http://mydevice.io/) shows it (as pixel ratio). You can take a look at the scripts with inspect element, if you dare :D.